# Display records with TextBox

Tags: vb.net

With this code, the number of random records to display is fixed and hardcoded in the command text ("Top 10"). How to remove the number (Top 10) from the code and replace it with the value of TextBox1 and I write the variable number of records I want to display in Datagridview1?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataBase_Connection()
    InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(" SELECT Top 10 ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())", ConStr)
    InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
    InfoTable = New DataTable()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, something like the following should work fine:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim rows As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, rows) Then
        ' Invalid number. You can display a MessageBox or something.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    DataBase_Connection()
    ' Works with VS2015 and above:
    'Dim sql As String = $"SELECT Top {rows} ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())"

    ' Works with VS2013 and below:
    Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM FACTORY ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())",
                                      rows)
    InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, ConStr)
    InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
    InfoTable = New DataTable()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable
End Sub
```

Where `Integer.TryParse()` is used to validate the input being an Integer value.

### References:

- [`Integer.TryParse()` docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse).
- [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings).

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for help.But i have an error ( Blue line ) below ( Integer.TryCast ) and sign of Dollar

Comment: My bad, It's `TryParse`, it was a typo and I fixed it. About the dollar sign, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: My apologies master Ahmed.. now i have a single error below sign of Dollar ( $ ) .. Character is not valid .. I work VS 2013. Thank you

Comment: VS2013 doesn't support Interpolated strings. You can use `String.Fromat()` instead. I included that in the answer.

Comment: Perfectly resolved.Thank you very much Ahmed Abdelhameed.And Good RamaDhan

Comment: @ABIDINE Don't leave your data connections open like that.  Close them when you aren't using them.

Comment: Thak you very much LarsTech for advice